# Popover not toggling off on click on the body

Tags: jquery

So, I have a popover which toggles show/hide perfectly fine on click on its glyphicons having ids as profile and notificationalert. But when I click on the body, it hides but doesn't toggle back on on the first click. It toggles ON on the second click on the glyphicons. 
How do I fix this?

```
$("#profile").on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 $.get('/userSettings').done(function(resp){
      $('#profile').attr('data-title','<b>'+resp.currentuser+'</b>');
      if(resp.fName && resp.fName!="" && resp.lName && resp.lName!=""){
        $('#profile').attr('data-content','<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true">'+" ("+resp.fName+" "+resp.lName+")"+'</span><p></p><p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span><a href="/profile">&nbsp;User Settings</a></p><p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span><a href="/users/logout">&nbsp;Signout</a></p>');
      }
      else{
        $('#profile').attr('data-content','<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span><a href="/profile">&nbsp;User Settings</a></p><p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span><a href="/users/logout">&nbsp;Signout</a></p>');

      }
      $('#profile').popover({html:true});
      $('#profile').popover('toggle');
      $('#notificationAlert').popover('toggle');
      }).fail(function(err){
      $('#profile').attr('data-content',"NO Alerts Found");
    });
   });

       $('body').on('click', function (e) {
    //did not click a popover toggle, or icon in popover toggle, or popover
    if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover'
        && $(e.target).parents('[data-toggle="popover"]').length === 0
        && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) { 
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('toggle');
    }
});
```

Comment: create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example of your problem so that we can check and rectify it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. It had to do with some other part of my scripts. I wasn't managing the session properly between users and subusers. Also, I wasn't sending `res.send({status:"success"});` to confirm that the event has infact asked it to be toggled on again.